# Manually Uninstall GDAL

Tags: apt, uninstall

I followed a `./configure`, `make`, `make install` approach when I originally installed GDAL on my Ubuntu machine, but now I want to upgrade to 1.10.

Unfortunately, I want to use apt to perform the upgrade, but after performing an `apt-get install` I run `gdal-config --version` I still get a version of 1.9.

I've tried manually renaming the .so files in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib` but I still am unable to manually uninstall GDAL.

Has anyone else had success doing this?

Comment: Does `make uninstall` do anything?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this will help, but it worked out for me. I was looking to upgrade GDAL, and since I had installed it manually from source, I wanted to uninstall the old version first. So I read somewhere (sorry but I had so many tabs open that I can't find it now) that I should just install the latest package and that would override the previous. And I read another comment saying next time instead of using `sudo make install` I should use `sudo checkinstall` which creates a deb package wich is uninstallable later running `sudo dpkg -r <name_of_your_package>` so I just installed the version I had with `sudo checkinstall` (overriding what I had, and creating the package) and then I uninstalled that using `sudo dpkg -r gdal`. I know it's not the most elegant thing, but it worked for me.

Comment: It might not be elegant, but it works like a charm!

Comment: This solution worked for me. However, I had trouble with QGIS not loading gdal afterwards due to Python2.7 bindings. I resolved this by removing to folder /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GDAL-1.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

Answer (score 3):

You need to locate your manually installed binary:

```
$> which gdalinfo
/usr/local/bin
```

And then you have to locate other manually installed binaries and remove them (**BEWARE BEFORE REMOVING COMMAND**: you certainly have other manually installed binaries here)

```
$> ls /usr/local/bin
gdal-config gdal_contour gdal_grid gdal_rasterize gdal_translate gdaladdo gdalbuildvrt gdaldem gdalenhance gdalinfo gdallocationinfo gdalmanage gdalserver gdalsrsinfo gdaltindex gdaltransform gdalwarp ogr2ogr ogrinfo ogrlineref ogrtindex
```

When you manually install GDAL, you also install local lib, they should be here: `/usr/local/lib/` with the `libgdal*` wildcard and inside `gdalplugins`. You'll want to remove them also.